# Can Button.Click event handler be interrupted by BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event handler?

Tags: winforms, backgroundworker, buttonclick

I'm writing a Windows Forms application, with an intensive use of BackgroundWorkers, and there is a question that worries me. Here is a sample situation:

1. BackgroundWorker executes it's time-consuming operations.
2. While BackgroundWorker is still running, User presses the Button on the Form.
3. Button.Click event handler starts it's execution, completes some statements, but there are more of them.
4. At this moment, BackgroundWorker completes it's task, or raises an exception, so the control should go to BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Well, my question is: Is there any possibility for BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted event handler to interrupt the execution of Button.Click event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `DoWork` finishes, `RunWorkerCompleted` will be invoked on the thread that launched `BackgroundWorker`. Let's say it's the main thread. This means it will post a message on the main-thread's message queue. If the main-thread is currently handling a message (e.g. a Button.Click event), then `RunWorkerCompleted` will sit on the thread's message queue until it turn arrives. Meaning - it will not interrupt / collide-with the button event handler.